Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account. The problem at signer, but I don't know why is it wrong??. Please help me
#[derive(AnchorDeserialize, AnchorSerialize)]
pub struct UpdateNFTParams {
id: String,
name: String,
symbol: String,
uri: String,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: UpdateNFTParams)]
pub struct UpdateNFT<'info> {
#[account(
mut,
mint::decimals = 0,
mint::authority = nft_pda
)]
pub mint_nft: Account<'info, Mint>,
#[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [NFTPda::SEED_PREFIX, params.id.as_bytes().as_ref()],
    bump
)]
pub nft_pda: Account<'info, NFTPda>,

/// CHECK: From metaplex
#[account(mut)]
pub metadata_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
/// CHECK: From metaplex
#[account(mut)]
pub master_edition_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
pub buyer: Signer<'info>,
pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,

}
pub fn update_nft_handler(ctx: Context, params: UpdateNFTParams) -> Result<()> {
let mint_nft = &ctx.accounts.mint_nft;
let metadata_account = &ctx.accounts.metadata_account;
let master_edition_account = &ctx.accounts.master_edition_account;
let token_metadata_program = &ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program;
let token_program = &ctx.accounts.token_program;
let system_program = &ctx.accounts.system_program;
let buyer = &ctx.accounts.buyer;
let rent = &ctx.accounts.rent;
let nft_pda = &ctx.accounts.nft_pda;
let cpi_program = token_metadata_program.to_account_info().clone();
let cpi_accounts = CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
    metadata: metadata_account.to_account_info(),
    mint: mint_nft.to_account_info(),
    mint_authority: nft_pda.to_account_info(),
    update_authority: nft_pda.to_account_info(),

    payer: buyer.to_account_info(),
    system_program: system_program.to_account_info(),
    rent: rent.to_account_info(),
};

let seed_mint = NFTPda::SEED_PREFIX;
let seeds = &[seed_mint, &params.id.as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.nft_pda]];
let signer = &[&seeds[..]];

let cpi_ctx_update_metadata = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);

let creators = vec![Creator {
    address: buyer.key(),
    verified: false,
    share: 100,
}];

let data_v2 = DataV2 {
    name: params.name.clone(),
    symbol: params.symbol.clone(),
    uri: params.uri.clone(),
    seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
    creators: Some(creators.clone()),
    collection: None,
    uses: None,
};
create_metadata_accounts_v3(cpi_ctx_update_metadata, data_v2, false, true, None)?;

let cpi_program = token_metadata_program.to_account_info().clone();
let cpi_accounts = CreateMasterEditionV3 {
    edition: master_edition_account.to_account_info(),
    mint: mint_nft.to_account_info(),
    mint_authority: nft_pda.to_account_info(),
    update_authority: nft_pda.to_account_info(),
    payer: buyer.to_account_info(),
    metadata: metadata_account.to_account_info(),
    token_program: token_program.to_account_info(),
    system_program: system_program.to_account_info(),
    rent: rent.to_account_info(),
};

let seed_mint = NFTPda::SEED_PREFIX;
let seeds = &[seed_mint, &params.id.as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.nft_pda]];
let signer = &[&seeds[..]];

let cpi_ctx_update_master_edition =
    CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);

create_master_edition_v3(cpi_ctx_update_master_edition, None)?;

Ok(())

}
